# is it possible to make phone ring based on the notification received via BLE,

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to send the notification to the andorid phone ( using NRF51DK bluetooth BLE)my concept is press the bitton on the NRF51DK and it will send notification to the phone and by using that notification does it possible for the android app developer to make phone ring? can anybody please verify with my concept am i right or wrong? if wrong what are the other possible ways to do that

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I Think phone call to another phone number is possible.
But it will be impossible to make my phone receive call.. if it imeans real call.. not just sound.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make the phone ring based on the notification received via ble device such as NRF51DK.

Use this library to send and receive data from and to that ble device with your android app - https://github.com/richhowley/Android-BLE-to-Arduino

And just when you get any specific kind of message from ble device just place the simple code for making a beep sound or notification in android applications.

It is that simple.